# Pushforward: from measure theory to differential geometry?

Tags: measure-theory, differential-geometry, category-theory, pushforward

I was wondering if there is a connection between the pushforward from measure theory, and the pushforward from differential geometry?

**In measure theory**: let $X:(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mu) \to \mathbb{R}$ a random variable. The pushforward measure is then defined as
$$
\nu = X_\#\mu = \mu \circ P^{-1}
$$
and defines a measure on $\mathbb{R}$. Hence, we push the measure $\mu$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

**In differential geometry**: let $\phi:M \to N$ be a smooth map between two manifolds. The pushforward differential is a map
$$
d\phi(x): T_xM \to T_{\phi(x)}N.
$$ Hence, we push a tangent vector of $M$ to a tangent vector of $N$.

I understand both definitions. But I am not sure I understand the relation correctly. Is there even a relation? Can we interpret the pushforward differential as a measure? Is the relation given by the Radon-Nikdoym theorem?

Any idea is welcome.

Comment: The pushforward is a more general notion, and is formally defined in category theory. In a very informal non-categorical sense, both the differential and pushforward measure do the same thing, by using a function defined between two spaces (that "pushes" points to points) that then push measures to measures and tangent vectors to tangent vectors.

Comment: One can rephrase the definitions so that they're even more similar. If $\mu$ is identified with the functional $\mu(f) = \int f d\mu$ on $f \in C(\Omega)$, the pushforward is $X_\# \mu(f) := \mu(f \circ X)$. If a tangent vector $v$ (at $x$) is identified with the directional derivative $V = \partial_v$, then the pushforward (at $x$) is $d\phi(V) := V(f \circ \phi)$.

Comment: The last formula should be $(d \phi \, V)(f) := V(f \circ \phi)$, of course.

Comment: It’s actually a little confusing. The analogue in differential geometry of a measure is a differential form. But although you push forward measures, you pull back forms. You do push forward vector fields. Here’s a crucial difference between the two different pushforwards, the pushforward of a vector field is not a vector field but the push forward of a measure is a measure. It’s important to understand what’s going on with each case and why they’re different.

Comment: @rubikscube09 I am curious about how to construct the pushforward in differential geometry as a pushout in the category of smooth manifolds. It doesn't seem obvious to me, I've tried messing around with pushout diagrams.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a connection because the concept of **pushforward** is a general notion in mathematics, besides it formalization in category theory or whatever, it is the notion of induction of an structure in a mathematical space from another through a function $f:X\to Y$.

That is: we use the function $f$ to induce some kind of structure on $Y$ from an structure of the same kind in $X$, then we says that *we push forward a kind of structure of $X$ on $Y$ using $f$*. This is all. Then you can pushforward measures, vector fields (under some conditions), topologies, algebras, etc...